# Use custom mail address when sending transaction mails?

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail

**Magento 1.9**

This is my code:

```
$mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                    ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                    ->sendTransactional(
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                        null,
                        array('data' => $postObject)
                    );
```

I want to set a custom sender so I tried to replace this line

```
Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER)
```

with something like

```
'test@example.com'
```

Does not work! Any idea how to make this work?

Thanks